# fullcalendar is working fine in localhost but not in server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

I have a calendar which displays the events from the database. The calendar works perfectly in localhost, but when I uploaded it, the events doesn't display.

[image]

Comment: ASP? or PHP?...

Comment: asp. please help me

Comment: How do you install jquery/fullcalendar? using Nuget or the include in project? And have you check the property of your scripts if deploy type is "Content"?

Comment: default. What do you think is the problem?

Comment: Christian Mark ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do 2 things,

Either you reference full-calendar using [CDN](https://fullcalendar.io/download/):

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.0.1/fullcalendar.min.js
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.0.1/fullcalendar.min.css
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.0.1/fullcalendar.print.css
```

Or install it using [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Fullcalendar/):

```
Install-Package jQuery.Fullcalendar
```

You have to make sure that the codes are deploy type:"Content" with "Copy Always"

On the other hand, you can check your codes if loaded properly using "Ctrl+Shift+I" - (inspect element) in Google Chrome.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Comment: Usually, servers restrict CDN's for security purposes. The 2nd option is a more appropriate choice.

Comment: Aha! I see that the code you are referencing is still in localhost. Can you show me how you reference your full-calendar?

Comment: what to do? why is that?

Comment: 1st, you are using PHP not ASP.
2nd, you are referencing using localhost not the one in your server

Comment: <a href="../../fullcalendar-2.4.0/demos/default.php">

Comment: Not that one: I mean the one in the header.
Yung nasa <header> tag. or yung nasa bottom part na may mga .js file

Comment: it is the localhost of the server.

Comment: @AbbyLazaro, try to add this to your html code:

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.0.1/fullcalendar.min.js"/>

Comment: sa default.php ko iadd?

Comment: forbidden access.

Comment: oo, pero kasi template yung gamit mo so I assume na dapat tama na referencing nyan. paano ka ba nag-ppublish sa server niyo?

Comment: same lang kung paano ko gipublish sa localhost. pinalitan ko lang yung connections.

Comment: as in copy paste or FTP? if FTP kasi need mo rin palitan yung source sa file reference mo.

like from "localhost" to "tngcserver.noip.me"

Comment: sir okay na po. Thank you very much. sa referencing nga po ang mali, instead of localhost yung name ng server nilagay ko. thanks po Sir :)

Comment: yep. I saw your website. NP.